# KeyError : whenever i change the active layer from the combo box of plugin it gives me keyError

Tags: qgis, pyqgis-3

I have used the QgsFieldExpressionWidget to build an expression and then evaluate it.
but whenever i try to change the layer from the plugin , it gives me this error.

[image]

this is my code:

self.cb_layer = QgsMapLayerComboBox()

self.field_expression_widget = QgsFieldExpressionWidget()

self.expr_outputField_cb = QgsFieldComboBox()

def change_layer(self):

```
    self.dlg.cb_layer.clear()

    layers = self.iface.legendInterface().layers

    layer_list = [layer.name() for layer in layers]

    self.dlg.cb_layer.addItems(layer_list)
```

def expression_widget(self):

```
  layer = self.dlg.cb_layer.currentLayer()

    self.dlg.field_expression_widget.setLayer(layer)

    
    scope = QgsExpressionContextUtils.layerScope(layer)

    scope.setFields(layer.fields())

    self.field_expression_widget.appendScope(scope)
```

self.field_expression_widget.registerExpressionContextGenerator(layer)

```
    result_field = self.dlg.expr_outputField_cb.currentField()
    
   
    
    layer.startEditing()
  
    print(QgsExpression(self.dlg.field_expression_widget.currentText()))
   
    
    expression1 = QgsExpression(self.dlg.field_expression_widget.currentText())
    
    context = QgsExpressionContext()
    context.appendScopes(QgsExpressionContextUtils.globalProjectLayerScopes(layer))
    
    
    for f in layer.getFeatures():     
        context.setFeature(f)
        f[result_field] = expression1.evaluate(context)
        layer.updateFeature(f)
```

def run(self):

```
                                                                           self.dlg.field_expression_widget.setLayer(self.dlg.cb_layer.currentLayer())
```

self.dlg.cb_layer.layerChanged.connect(self.expression_widget)
self.dlg.produce_result_btn.clicked.connect(self.expression_widget)

Comment: Not sure if you got my comments to your previous question: https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/440615/error-in-storing-the-result-of-the-the-expression-of-the-qgsfieldexpressionwidge I can only reiterate my suggestion: keep a reference to the current layer in your map layer combo box and set it (along with scope/fields/ whatever) to your `QgsFieldExpressionWidget` outside of your `expression_widget()` method.

Comment: Do this wherever your `self.dlg` object is created in your plugin and also put the logic into another class method which you connect to the `layerChanged` signal of your `QgsMapLayerComboBox`. Example: https://gist.github.com/benwirf/8af9894e52087d3a516a420e5522cfeb

Comment: I still dont get it. I will update the whole code in question kindly tell me where to do what.